# How can I get all feed entries from a page like Google Reader? (Since RSS is transitory)

Tags: php, rss, google-reader

I'm trying to build a script to retrieve all feed entries from a given page, but I can get only the most recents. How does Google Reader do it?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to fetch feed entries that are no longer available?

Comment: Yes, like google reader. I've found this as example: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/reconstruct-feeds-history-using-google.html
I think I'll need to follow each feed and store the information each time it is updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they just store it. Once someone adds it to their list, Google Reader starts archiving and saving each entry.

If you find an obscure feed, you'll find it can't go back since before you started using it.

Comment: This is indeed exactly what they did. However, Google Reader shut down on July 1st 2013. Replacements include services like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com)

Answer (score 1):

Most feed-generating scripts are programmed to only include a specified number of entires, say the ten most recent posts to a blog. Google reader does, as was said before, download and archive all new posts from each unique feed in its users' readers. That's why you can view older materials on it.

If the page is your own, you could try increasing the number of entires included in the RSS feed. Otherwise, there is no way to retrieve entries from a page via RSS if those entries are no longer available in the feed.

Comment: Actually, there is a way to do that through google reader: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/06/reconstruct-feeds-history-using-google.html

Comment: That's very handy, and I didn't know you could do that, but it still doesn't solve the problem of retrieving data that isn't being fed to the RSS script any longer, and that hasn't been cached by Google (in obscure feeds, as was suggested earlier).

This is probably not the case for most sites many people subscribe to, though, as they will probably have had at least one subscriber as far back as anyone cares to look. For less popular sites, though, there may be a problem. For example, my own blog only has 106 posts archived, out of 197 total.